# Debezium MSSQL "Producer failure Column not found in result set" after schema change and incremental snapshot

Tags: sql-server, debezium

After adding a column to one of the source tables for an MSSQL Debezium connector, and then attempting an incremental snapshot on the table, the connector fails with the following error:

```
[2023-03-27 01:20:06,176] ERROR [source|task-0] Producer failure (io.debezium.pipeline.ErrorHandler:35)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Error while processing event at offset {transaction_id=null, event_serial_no=1, incremental_snapshot_maximum_key=0123456, commit_lsn=0123456:0123456:0003, change_lsn=0123456:0123456:0002, incremental_snapshot_collections=SOURCE.dbo.TaxIdentification, incremental_snapshot_primary_key=0123456}
    at io.debezium.pipeline.EventDispatcher.dispatchDataChangeEvent(EventDispatcher.java:246)
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerStreamingChangeEventSource.lambda$executeIteration$1(SqlServerStreamingChangeEventSource.java:290)
    at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareQuery(JdbcConnection.java:606)
    at io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnection.getChangesForTables(SqlServerConnection.java:329)
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Column 'Column3' not found in result set 'Column1, Column2, Column3' for table 'Database.dbo.Table', columns: {
Column1 int(10, 0) NOT NULL
Column2 int(10, 0) NOT NULL
}
primary key: [Column1]
default charset: null
comment: null
. This might be caused by DBZ-4350
    at io.debezium.util.ColumnUtils.toArray(ColumnUtils.java:57)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.source.snapshot.incremental.AbstractIncrementalSnapshotChangeEventSource.lambda$readChunk$2(AbstractIncrementalSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:299)
```

The debezium documentation [says](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.9/connectors/sqlserver.html#online-schema-updates) that incremental snapshots don't play nicely with schema changes, so obviously this is not good.

The question is, now that this *has* happened, how do we get the connector healthy again? We've already tried:

1. creating the new CDC capture instance for the table (and leaving the old one)
2. clearing out the debezium_signal table and then pausing/restarting the connector

the connector is still giving the `Producer failure` error when starting up.

Answer (score -1):

It took us a few days, but we eventually found a way to get the connector healthy again:

Remove the table from the debezium connector's config (`table.include.list`) and add it straight back.

Once the connector starts up healthy, do the online (or offline) [schema update procedure](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.9/connectors/sqlserver.html#online-schema-updates),

Once the new CDC capture table is created, you can do incremental snapshots without causing the connector to fail. Delete the old capture table either immediately or at some later point.

Comment: Thanks for adding your own solution. I also see this error on sqlserver, and my approach was to "tombstone" the connector (submit an null event to the offsets topic with connector's key). However, that forces a full re-read of all tables associated with that connector, so I prefer your solution.

Comment: This did not work for us, how successful has this been for others? Simplying deleting the config and redeploying we seem to be continue getting the Producer Failure error

Comment: I have tried this approach, It didn't work for me.